# Excel formula to find h:mm am/pm from a line of dynamic text

Tags: excel, timestamp, excel-formula, formula

I have a string below which updated every 10 or so minutes.

```
Last Updated as of 8:22 am Auguest 30th blah blah blah
```

I am interested only in `8:22 am`. I know I can use `=MID()` & `=find()` to grab it but does anybody have easier way to do it ?

Comment: Not really, no.  AFAIK, `MID()` + `FIND()` is going to be your best bet.  You *could* use VBA by including `'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions` and the use regular expressions (http://superuser.com/questions/181005/can-you-do-regular-expressions-in-excel-without-vbscript), but yuck.

Comment: Is "blah blah blah" constant, or does that part change?

Comment: @DougGlancy that part does also changes but only in length. from 1 to 999,999.

Comment: @pnuts lol, You are right both give us same solution. I guess all I can tell you that I was looking for different solution then `=mid()` which I already knew. I learned something new with Doug's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the width of the time will only vary by one character, I think this works for you:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Last Updated as of ",""),8))
```

Comment: This is clever Thanks.

Comment: I think it's easier than `Mid` and `Find`, but matzone's is simpler still, although I would add `TRIM` to it as well. As far as "hidden features" I make no claims in that regard. I'm just a humble answerer of questions.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Last Updated as of` is always

you can use `= Mid(A1,20,8)` for A1 Cell

Comment: It is dynamic so lets say for example next month is May, and I already use that.

Comment: Month name won't a problem .. as you said `I am interested only in 8:22 am` .. or I've missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

`MID` and `FIND` would be the fastest/easiest way to pull that information out.

Comment: I know I couldn't think of anything else that's why asking for help here.